# SQL SELECT COUNT of different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, count

I have a table with following sample data

```
   IP          URL
=========   ========
1.1.1.1       aaaa
2.2.2.2       bbbb
1.1.1.1       ffff
1.1.1.1       aaaa
3.3.3.3       ssss
5.5.5.5       aaaa
7.7.7.7       bbbb
4.4.4.4       aaaa
1.1.1.1       aaaa
3.3.3.3       bbbb
5.5.5.5       aaaa
```

I need to select this result:

```
 IP        URL    Total count of related IPs     Total count of current IP for current URL  
                             (DESC SORT)
=======   =====  =============================  ===========================================  
1.1.1.1   aaaa                6                                     3  
5.5.5.5   aaaa                6                                     2
4.4.4.4   aaaa                6                                     1
2.2.2.2   bbbb                3                                     1
7.7.7.7   bbbb                3                                     1
3.3.3.3   bbbb                3                                     1
1.1.1.1   ffff                1                                     1
3.3.3.3   ssss                1                                     1
```

I used some query like the following but didnt success to get the exact result:

```
SELECT ip, url, COUNT(ip) totalip FROM mytable
GROUP BY url ORDER BY totalip DESC
```

appreciate for any help

Comment: Could you provide a bit more description on the search pattern that query needs to perform? After seeing expected results, I'm not fully sure of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can do it with COUNT() window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP, URL,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY URL) Total_count_of_related_IPs,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY IP, URL) Total_count_of_current_IP_for_current_URL
FROM tablename
ORDER BY Total_count_of_related_IPs DESC
```

For previous versions, use a self join and aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.IP, t1.URL,
       COUNT(*) Total_count_of_related_IPs,
       SUM(t1.IP = t2.IP) Total_count_of_current_IP_for_current_URL
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tablename) t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.URL = t1.URL
GROUP BY t1.IP, t1.URL
ORDER BY Total_count_of_related_IPs DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b019e6fe6fff14d04ea222ada742e51).

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate and window function

```
select IP, URL, 
   sum(count(*)) over(partition by URL) TotalCountOf RelatedIPs, 
   count(*) TotalCountOfCurrentIPForCurrentURL 
from tbl
group by IP, URL
order by URL, IP;
```

Comment: Sort by Total count of related IPs DESC